# How to send data to tcp server from command prompt

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, tcp, tcpip

I am a java developer and quite aware of socket programming in java.I have a tcp server running my localmachine.I can write java codes for client and check communication between server and client.But I wanted to know if can communicate with the server from command prompt in windows.

I am using windows 7 operating system and the tcp port is 6002.So can any body please tell how to send data from windows command prompt

Comment: I don't care what anybody says but there is no such thing as a `TCP server`. You have a server that runs a process/service that communicates via TCP port 6002. That does not make it a `TCP server`. Have you tried using Telnet?

Comment: @joeqwerty by telnet localhost 6002 I can connect with it.But I dont know how to send data

Comment: Once you connect through `telnet,` you just start typing. The program will send what you type to the server, and print what the server sends back to your terminal. You would have to know what data you want to send to the server, of course.

Comment: @Kenster when I type telnet localhost 6002 then another window opens and I can not see anything that I type.Only a cursor appears

Comment: You can run tcpdump on the server to watch that interface and port for the data going back and forth from the client. What is your end goal? Are you just simply trying to prove that traffic is passing?

Comment: @joeqwerty: I've seen the term used to differentiate from something listening and only accepting UDP connections, i.e. in contrast to "UDP server."

Comment: @joeqwerty I would say that a web server is both a HTTP and TCP server. It all depends on which OSI layer you are observing.

Comment: That's like saying a web server is an IP server, or a Data-Link Layer server. You could call it anything you want in relation to any of the 7 OSI layers. A server may use TCP as it's transport mechanism but that doesn't make it a TCP server. It does not `serve` TCP. A server `serves`. You can `serve` HTTP or HTTPS, or you can `serve` CIFS or NFS, but you can't `serve` TCP.

Comment: @MaQleod I have done cleint and sever in java.Now when both are running client sends binary data to server and the server acknoledges to client also in binary format.Now suppose my server is running and after that in command prompt i have typed telnet localhost 6002 then it just connects to sever but I want to how to send binary data to server

Comment: It sounds as though your server is setup to respond to specific data from the client - in other words, you are using TCP sockets but the query and response pattern is specific to your custom application. Telnet would not be the ideal way to copy this over the command line. You can call system.net.sockets from powershell in order to send/receive data like that.

Comment: @MaQleod so can I do in command prompt?I do not want to use java code to send data to server.

Comment: Here is a rough example using powershell: http://www.skipdaflip.nl/powershell/communicate-through-tcp-with-powershell/

Comment: @MaQleod In which language its written,I know only java

Comment: it is part of the .NET framework and can be used in a variety of languages (vbscript, visual basic, c#, c++, f#, or directly in powershell): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Sockets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx   Here is a quick rundown on calling .NET methods in powershell: http://sreerenjnair.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/how-to-call-a-net-method-in-powershell-2-0/

Comment: @MaQleod Thanks,I am hearing the word power shell for the 1st time.I dont know how to use also and that too .net also new to me.I have never used it.But thanks,I wont disturb you much

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP used to have a `telnet` command that was useful for "quick and dirty" testing if a TCP server was alive and reachable.

`telnet {IP-address} {port}`

i.e. `telnet microsoft.com 80`

If no service is listening, you will get an error message.
If it's blocked by a firewall, it will timeout.

If the service outputs something upon connection, you will see it.  However, it may be waiting for you to send something.  In the case above, type `GET / http/1.1`, hit enter twice, and you'll see the HTML of http://microsoft.com.

With Windows 7, you can install the "Telnet Client" from Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off, or use PuTTY for this purpose.

You can also use a better tool for this purpose called [netcat](http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/).

Comment: Thanks for answering.I have done a tcp server configuration which just listen at 6002 port and local ip.It will also accept binary data.so after receiving it will also acknoledge data in binary format.I have done both client and server in java.If I run both client and sever in java then it works properly(meaning sending and getting data).Just I am curious to know how to send data in telnet. Becuase when I do telnet localhost 6002 then it only connects to server and in the server console I can see client is connected.But I want to  know how can I send data